# Proving that there are no other integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The integer solutions for this equation:
$m ^ 2 = 2 \cdot 3 ^ n - 5$ 
are these four couples: $(n; m): (1;-1) (1;1) (3;7) (3;-7)$.

> How can I prove there are no other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One mechanical way is to reduce this to a finite number of Mordell curves: $3^n$ always belongs to one of the forms $r^3$, $3r^3$, or $9r^3$.  Doing a simple change of variables transforms each of these possibilities into an equation of the form $y^2 = x^3 - N$, where $N \in \{20, 180, 1620\}$.  There are precomputed tables of solutions to these curves, and while OEIS doesn't carry the solutions themselves, it does tabulate the number of integer points at http://oeis.org/A081120:

- $N=20$ has $2$ points, so they must be $(x,y) = (6,\pm 14)$ corresponding to your solutions $(n,m) = (3,\pm 7)$ after unravelling the change of variables.
- $N=180$ has $2$ points, so they must be $(x,y) = (6,\pm 6)$ corresponding to $(n,m) = (1,\pm 1)$.
- $N=1620$ has no integer points, so all solutions are accounted for.

**Edit:** In the comments, Peter points out that there is a significant error in the OEIS listing for $N=180$ (which likely indicates more errors).  There is an additional solution $(x,y) = (69,\pm 573)$, but this leads to a half-integer value of $m = \frac{191}{2}$ and an irrational value for $n$, so it doesn't contribute a new solution to the original equation.

Comment: A nice proof with the Mordell-curve ( (+1) for that idea ). Recently, I found an error in the OEIS-sequence, but not in the sequence you mentioned. In the sequence of $k$, such that $y^2=x^3-n$ has no integer points, two wrong entries occured (See here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193384/i-think-i-found-an-error-in-a-oeis-sequence-what-is-the-proper-site-to-post-it).

Comment: Mike Bennett's table reveals that for $N=180$, we have $4$ integral points : $$-180 4 [69,573] [69,-573] [6,6] [6,-6]$$ and for $N=1620$, the table approves that there is no solution. Perhaps, you try to fill up the gap in my approach , using pell-like equations. This would allow a much easier proof.

Comment: @Peter Wow, thanks for this very informative correction!

Answer (score 3):

An even $n$ cannot lead to a solution because the equation can be rewritten as $$m^2-2k^2=-5$$ since $3^n$ is a square, but this equation has no solution modulo $25$, hence no solutions in the integers.

If $n$ is odd and $n\ge 5$, the equation can be rewritten as $$m^2-486k^2=-5$$

The convergents $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{486}$ satisfy $$p_n^2-486q_n^2=-2$$ for odd n and $$p_n^2-486q_n^2=1$$ for even $n$

Since $|-5|=5<\sqrt{486}$ and $-5$ does not occur in the sequence $p_n^2-486q_n^2$, we can conclude that $m^2-486k^2=-5$ has no integer solution. This completes the proof that there are no solutions for $n\ge 5$

Comment: The fundamental unit here is $5 + 2\sqrt{6}$, so it looks like you have two interleaved sequences each following the recurrence $m' = 5m + 12k, k' = 2m + 5k$.

Comment: @ErickWong Seems that this reccurence relation leads to the proof! I noticed that the remainder pairs modulo $9$ quickly get into a cycle and $0$ is never reached. This implies that $k$ is never divisble by $9$ ($m$ is never divisble by $9$ either, but this is not important here). So first, we have to prove that ALL solutions are given by the above relation and then my claim.

Comment: Nice!  It's relatively simple in principle to prove that all solutions come from the two basic solutions $(1,1)$ and $(7,3)$.  The basic idea is that if you have a solution $(m,k)$, extract a new solution by reversing the recurrence (i.e. multiplying by $5-2\sqrt{6}$).  For large $m,k$ we have $m \approx \sqrt{6}k$ with very small error $O(1/k)$, so one can show that the new solution is smaller than before.  Thus every solution can be traced back to one with "small" values of $m,k$, which can be searched by computation.

Comment: @ErickWong Not necessary, I found an easier variant (See answer above)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach.

Since $m$ is odd, let $m = 2k + 1$

We have $4k^2 + 4k + 6 = 2*3^n \implies 2k^2 + 2k + 3 = 3^n \implies 2k(k+1) = 3(3^{n-1} - 1)$

So $3$ has to divide $k$ or $k+1$ and $3$ cannot be a factor of both $k$ and $k+1$.

If $3$ divides $k$, then $k$ divides $3 \implies k = 3 \implies m = 7, n = 3$

If $3$ divides $k$ and $k+1$ divides $3 \implies k = 0, m = 1, n = 1$

Comment: "If $3$ divides $k$, then $k$ divides $3$" is not correct.

Comment: I tried this approach as well, but it led to nowhere

Comment: @peter, the argument is correct since k has to divide the right hand side and $k$ which has $3$ as a factor cannot divide $3^{n-1} - 1$

Comment: The argument only holds if $k$ is a prime. If $k$ is composite, it can divide the right side even if it is divisible by $3$ because we have a cofactor that can divide $3^{n-1}-1$

Comment: @Peter, thank you. I have a proof that shows k(k+1) is of the form 6y(y+1). Can we conclude that this has only the trivial solutions k = 0, k = 3 and k = 8 and hence original equation has only two solutions?

Comment: I don't think this works. Seems that we need the more complicated pell-like- equations to solve the problem, but at least we do not need the even more complicated mordell-curves. What might work, is using the gaussian integers. With the help of them (and the unique factorization within them) all solution of some Mordell-curves can be calculated, well possible that we can use it here as well. If you want, try it, and good luck :)