# Methods and tricks for finding patterns in sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, problem-solving

I'm currently working on a problem for finding an exact formula for a recursively defined sequence of numbers (set of indices is $\mathbb N^m$).

I know some methods for finding (or guessing) such formulas like for linear recursive equations with constant coefficients or writing down several members with small numbers or writing conditions for generating function.

So, what I want is some broad variety of techniques for pattern-guessing and pattern-finding in sequences. I was looking in books on olympiad problem solving - but didn't find very much (except for telescopic method and some substitutional tricks).

This will be a non-closing question for collecting as much ideas as possible.

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) is your friend.

Comment: @Lovsovs There was I time I trusted OEIS, at least the "approved" sequences. But I noticed that even approved sequences contained wrong entries. Nevertheless, OEIS is usefull to find possible patterns.

Comment: @Peter Do you have examples of sequences that contain errors? I ask because I do a fair share of editing/assisting of OEIS sequences.

Comment: Check the sequence in this question (Maybe it is fixed now) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193384/i-think-i-found-an-error-in-a-oeis-sequence-what-is-the-proper-site-to-post-it/2230886#2230886